# I was excited to learn that you have returned to town

Tags: tense

> I was excited to learn that you have returned to town.

If the person returned three years ago, is it correct to use "that you have returned"?

Comment: Yes, it's possible if the speaker has only just learned the fact!

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I am confused. I think the person returned 3 years ago and the speaker has just found it out. So, the speaker is talking about his current feelings. In that case, shouldn't he have said "I AM excited to learn that you have returned to town." instead of "I WAS excited ....."?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was the tense of _returned_ that OP was asking about. Yes, certainly it should be _am_ if the speaker has only just found out. If the sentence is about their feelings three years ago, it should be _I was excited to learn that you **had** returned to town_.

Comment: If you were excited when you learned and are still excited, then it's ok to use past to emphasize you're talking about the initial reaction. Since you must be speaking after you learned of their return it's not wrong to use the past, though present is also possible.

Comment: Kate Bunting, actually I meant by "I was excited" that it was yesterday that I learned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is correct, the situation that the person returned three years ago  is located in past time. But if I utter "Jimmy returned three yeas ago", Jimmy returning located in past time and the reference time is present. In your case, you returning to town is located in past time,but the reference time is the subject feel excited, which is located in past time.